# Як перекладаються Writing, Reading, Speaking, Listening в значенні етапів мовного екзамену або складових мови?

Tags: from-english

На екзаменах типу [IELTS](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/IELTS) є наступні етапи: Writing, Reading, Speaking, Listening. Я хотів би дізнатись як правильно перекладати назви цих етапів українською.

Також ці слова можна розглядати як назви складових мови. Якщо в цьому значенні переклад має бути відмінним від перекладу назв етапів екзамену, то буду вдячний за пояснення відмінностей.

Comment: Я б сказав: письмо, читання, правопис (чи орфографія) і аудіювання (чи прослуховування). Перші два слова — це те, як воно, здається, називається в початкових класах школи. (Ще, як я пам'ятаю, у середній класах школи вивчали назви розділів науки про мову — як-от: фонетика, графіка, орфоепія, орфографія, лексика, морфологія тощо — але навряд Ви серед них знайдете прямі відповідники цим етапам.)

Comment: Маю сумнїв, же то складови мови, скільки просто основні і загальні способи книжної мови, єсть шче, наприклад, [мигова](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Українська_жестова_мова).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Частини IELTS це *не* Writing, Reading, *Spelling*, Listening, а: Listening, Reading, Writing, **Speaking** - перевірити можна на [сайті](https://takeielts.britishcouncil.org/take-ielts/prepare/courses/free-online-course) британської ради.

Та сама британська рада [перекладає](http://www.britishcouncil.org.ua/exam/ielts/which-test/general-training) ці розділи як:

> тест складається з чотирьох розділів, це **слухання, читання, письмо** та **говоріння**.

Є альтернативні переклади від різних аґенцій.

Наприклад, international language center перекладає ці частини іспиту як "аудіювання, читання, письмова частина, усна мова"; а studway розуміють це як "розмовний модуль (Speaking), модуль зі слухання (Listening), читання (Reading) і письмо (Writing)".

Але "правильним" варіантом, від якого можна відштовхуватися, я би вважав сайт британської ради, адже саме в їхніх приміщеннях проводиться офіційне тестування.

Comment: Для рівноваги наростків _є_ можна додати _писанє_.

Comment: а чому не *писання*?

Comment: @Yola я думаю, це і малося на увазі. Просто у випадку stegetsj це буде писанє, читанє, слуханє, говорінє. Але я вигадувати тут нічого не хоче. Це ж про конкретний іспит питання.

Comment: Власне, це було питання до вас. Те, що одна з організацій, що проводить цей іспит так його називає не означає, що це правильно з мовної точки зору.

Comment: @Yola так а в чому проблема зі словом "письмо"?

Comment: має бути підстава для того, щоб три слова поставити в одній формі, а четверте в іншій

Comment: @Yola не думаю, що справді має бути підстава, якщо це слово широко вживане. В корпусі парасоль (ГРАК), наприклад, воно трапляється вдвічі частіше за "писання". Якщо врахувати, що і в першого, і в другого є інші значення, то однаково маємо частіше використання "письма", тому я би не прискіпувався до цього моменту. Впевнений, що серед 14 000 результатів знайду купу прикладів, коли "авторитетні люди" використовують "письмо" саме в потрібному тут значенні. Мова не має бути як проґрамний код)

Comment: Так, але ж я кажу про те, що у вас незлагоджено виходить, як червоний, червоний, жовтий, червоний.

Comment: @Yola я так само кажу, що мова не має бути як проґрамний код. Письмо там, за моїми припущеннями, просто через свою більшу частотність в українській мові.